# Finding points along a path

Tags: postgis, polygon, distance, route

I am unsure of the best approach to this problem. I can think of some ways of doing it which I will list below but I am looking for the best and most efficient way of doing this.

## Problem

- Given a variable number of points, create a "route" or line between the points.
- Create a bounding box (of 50km[arbitrary]) around the route.
- Return all points within this bounding box
- Points must be returned in order along the route (A->D)

Note: The radius does not have to be circles. A,B,C,D can use rectangular bounding boxes.

[image: Description of problem]

**Data**

- Table with points (x,y - technically lat/lon)
- Input points to create a route
- Distance from route to include points

We are using PostgreSQL (8.4) and PostGIS (1.3.6) and Python.

This is the solution I came up with. Thoughts? Ideas? Input?

## Possible Solution

- Create three polygon "tubes" (A->B, B->C, C->D)
- Filter points to only those in the polygons.
- Subtract B->C from A->B so the polygons do not overlap (no duplicates)
- Subtract C->D from B->C so the polygons do not overlap (no duplicates)
- For each polygon
- Calculate vector (A->B, B->C, C->D)
- Find furthest point opposite of vector in the polygon.
- Calculate distance from furthest point to each site in polygon.
- Return points in order of distance (smallest -> largest)
- Join all the points together (A->B points, B->C points, C->D points)

## Solution

My approach was naive, after taking some time and looking at the PostGIS methods I came up with this single SQL call. Note its specific to our database but might help someone in the future. Im sure it could be improved as well.

```
    SELECT aerodrome_id
    FROM
      geo_aerodromecustom_view, 
      (SELECT ST_Buffer(
          ST_Transform(
              (SELECT ST_MakeLine(geom) 
              FROM 
                  (SELECT geom 
                  FROM geo_aerodromecustom_view
                  WHERE aerodrome_id IN ('CYOW','CYVR') 
                  ORDER BY CASE aerodrome_id WHEN 'CYOW' THEN 1 WHEN 'CYVR' THEN 2 ELSE 5 END
                  ) sites
              ),
              900913
          ),
          50000) as geo
      ) as line
    WHERE ST_Intersects(ST_Transform(geom, 900913), line.geo)
    ORDER BY ST_Line_Locate_Point(
      ST_Transform(
          (SELECT ST_MakeLine(geom) 
           FROM 
              (SELECT geom 
               FROM geo_aerodromecustom_view
               WHERE aerodrome_id IN ('CYOW','CYVR') 
               ORDER BY CASE aerodrome_id WHEN 'CYOW' THEN 1 WHEN 'CYVR' THEN 2 ELSE 5 END
              ) sites
          ),
          900913
      ),
      ST_Transform(geom, 900913)
    )
```

I had to project the data because I am using PostGIS 1.3.4 which doesnt support Geography type.

Basically what I am doing is I am  using ST_MakeLine and a query to locate "aerodromes" and return their geometry.

I had to order them (using the CASE directive) so that the line would be connected in the right order.

I then project and buffer this line to create a Polygon that I can then use to see what other aerodromes intersect with the buffered polygon.

Using the unbuffered line (route) and the call ST_Line_Locate_Line I then order the discovered aerodromes as they appear appear along the path.

Comment: All but the last part of your question are answered in (multiple) threads on this site: there are many GPS-oriented questions telling how to make routes out of points; you want to *buffer* the route (a "bounding box" is altogether a different thing), and you want to select points by polygons (a "point-in-polygon" problem or "spatial selection"). The remaining question boils down to **how to sort a set of points by position along a given oriented polyline.**

Comment: Replace the pattern ST_Intersects(A, ST_Buffer(B, D)) with ST_DWithin(A, B, D) for a vastly more efficient query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need two postgis functions `ST_Buffer` and `ST_Line_Locate_Point`.

Comment: These were the calls I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to run a SQL statement using the PostGIS function [ST_LineLocatePoint](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineLocatePoint.html) to select the relative distance along the route.  You will need a single route, a filter for the max distance from the route, and an order by clause.

This is untested, but should get you started:

```
Select    points.pointID
from      points, 
          rountes 
where     rountes.routeID = :routeid 
  and     ST_Intersects(points.pointShape, ST_Buffer(route.rounteShape, 50000))
order by  ST_LineLocatePoint(route.rounteShape, points.pointShape);
```

You could filter by ST_Distance(points.pointShape, route.routeShape) <= 50000, but I'm not sure if that is going to use the spatial index.

---

Comment: Never mind, looks like Jukub beat me to it.

Comment: But certainly your answer is more full, my was kinda cheap.