# Finding locations within a radius of a given path

Tags: postgis, google-maps-api

I am trying to figure out in Postgis the right sql statement for the following:

- I have in my database a table of merchants with latitudes and longitudes;
- I have a route from google that lists a lot of latitude and longitude points for that path;
- I need to find all the merchants within 50 miles of that route.

I currently have a query that works for a single point, but it isn't performant to run the query over and over for each point returned by google (there can be thousands). Also, I am using a nodejs server, so I won't be able to multithread the process. Preferably the database would be doing all the work anyways.

Here's the query for the single point:

```
set search_path to my_schema, public;
SELECT m.*
FROM merchants m
WHERE ST_DWithin(
  Geography(ST_MakePoint(m.longitude, m.latitude)),
  Geography(ST_MakePoint(-94.6855231,38.9287475)),
  ( 50 * 1609.4 ) -- convert miles to meters
);
```

I don't even know where to start for the other solution.

Comment: I just found this in the questions, maybe it can be useful "Finding points along a path" http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70594/finding-points-along-a-path?rq=1. I don't really understand how the solution works, but I'm trying to figure out all the parts of the query. BTW, I'm a total Postgis noob. I have used it for about a week now. It is really cool though. Thanks.

Comment: I think you'll get better performance if you use `ST_Buffer` on the path to get the area that's within 50 miles of it, and then do an intersects on the set of merchant points.  That does depend a bit on the relative size of the linestring and the point cloud.

Comment: I'm going to head in to the office now. I will jump back on this after lunch. Thanks for your help thus far. I'll let you know how things are progressing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to format the LINESTRING (path) in your nodejs server :

Something like :

`LINESTRING(0 0, 1 1, ....)` --> `WKT FORMAT`

OR

`'{type : LineString, coordinates : [[0,0],[1,1], ...]}'` --> `GEOJSON FORMAT`

Now you should pass this to your query like this :

```
SELECT m.*
FROM merchants m
WHERE ST_Distance(ST_MakePoint(m.longitude, m.latitude), ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('GEOJSON PATH') < 50);
```

OR

```
SELECT m.*
FROM merchants m
WHERE ST_Distance(ST_MakePoint(m.longitude, m.latitude), ST_GeomFromText('YOUR WKT', SRID) < 50);
```

SRID in ST_GeomFromText() is optional

**Case**.

Imagine you have your path like this :

```
var path = [[0,0], ...]; // [long, lat]
var lineString = {
  type : 'LineString',
  coordinates : path
}
// Now do query to PostgreSQL.
```

For the query I suggest to use ST_DWithin, like you did, which is faster.

```
SELECT m.*
FROM merchants m
WHERE ST_DWithin(ST_MakePoint(m.longitude, m.latitude), ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('GEOJSON PATH'), 50 * 1609.4);
```

Comment: So for LINESTRING, is the [0,0] and the [1,1] really just longitude and latitude points, so it would be {type : LineString, coordinates : [[39.04632,-94.42422],[39.046260000000004,-94.42276000000001], ...]} ?

Comment: Yes! Inside the coordinates array you have to format the points as [longitude, latitude]. Make sure is [longitude, latitude] and not reverse. It seems in your comment you format as [latitude, longitude] : [[39.04632,-94.42422],[39.046260000000004,-94.42276000000001], ...] . But yes you catch it! Try it and let me know! =)